# How to map a domain to server?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, virtualhost, digital-ocean

My AngularJS application running on NGINX server user profiles. I want users to point their domains to their profiles.

**Example** http://example1.com would serve http://example.com/#/foo profile.

I have created a custom nameserver i.e. ns1.example.com but I am not sure how to configure NGINX to point to the correct user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that you'll want to handle at the application level, and not in Nginx.  That is, rather than updating and reloading your Nginx config files you should have something server side (like a lightweight Node.js application, for example) that would inspect the `Host` header.  If the `Host` header value isn't your domain, then look up that domain in your database and serve up a 301 redirect..

Also note that there are some compatibility problems with using a redirect to an anchor fragment (like `#/foo`).  Make sure you test well with the browsers that your users use most commonly.